# Calling integer method works but string method return null when call DLL from C++ in C#

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I am trying to implement a CLR concept on C++ and C#. I am create two simple method on C++.

this is `test.cpp` as main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

string SayHi(){
    return "hi";
}

int CallNumber(){
    return 911;
}
```

This is `test.h` as header

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" EXPORT_API string SayHi();
extern "C" EXPORT_API int CallNumber();
```

Then I compile them using

```
g++ -shared -o test.dll test.cpp
```

On my C# program, I try to call them

```
using System;

namespace Test.Main
{
  class Program
  {
    [DllImport(@"test.dll")]
    public static extern string SayHi();

    [DllImport(@"test.dll")]
    public static extern int CallNumber();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(SayHi());
      Console.WriteLine(CallNumber());
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

This program show

```
`dDO↓☻
911
```

The 911 integer works perfectly but the string show weird thing. And that `'dDO↓☻` always change every time I run the C# program.

I am using

- G++ version 9.4.0
- .Net Framework 4.8

Is there something I miss here? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: in c++, I do think you are missing `#include<string.h>`

Comment: @JamshaidK. he is using const char* not string